# JQuery Multiselect not working with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

In my ASP.net web application, I'm using JQuery Multi-selector. To populate the list box here I'm used Ajax call.

Sample JSON string

```
[{"UserId":10004,"FullName":"Wayne Pala"},{"UserId":10025,"FullName":"Danyel Pickering"},{"UserId":10027,"FullName":"Jina Sherlock"}]
```

Part of my code as follows,

```
<div class="col col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Users" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
        <asp:ListBox ID="ddlPlot" runat="server" Width="92%" TabIndex="6" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.multiSelect.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Common/kendo.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="../Stylesheets/jquery.multiSelect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetServicesList();
        createMultiSelectfor("Select Users...", "ddlPlot");
    });

    function GetServicesList() {
        "use strict";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: SERVER_PATH + '/LTSService/LTSService.asmx/GetAllUserData',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: UserComplete
        });
    }

    function UserComplete(result, status) {
        "use strict";
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);
        var lstsupervisor = $("[id*=ddlPlot]");
        lstsupervisor.empty();
        $.each(data, function () {
            lstsupervisor.append($("<option></option>").val(this['UserId']).html(this['FullName']));
        });
    }

    function createMultiSelectfor(placeholderText, listboxID) {
        $("#" + listboxID).multiSelect(
            {
                noneSelected: placeholderText,
                selectAll: true,
                oneOrMoreSelected: '*'
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Values bind to the list box properly. But the multi-select not working properly.

**current behavior**

[image]

**Expected behavior**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to initialize the jQuery plugin *before* the select list has been populated:

```
// This is an asynchronous operation:
GetServicesList();

// So this will start before the above has completed:
createMultiSelectfor("Select Users...", "ddlPlot");
```

Instead, initialize the plugin in your AJAX callback so it happens after the element is populated:

```
function UserComplete(result, status) {
    // the code you have already in this function
    // then...
    createMultiSelectfor("Select Users...", "ddlPlot");
}
```

Comment: David I have another question also. how can I pass **selected values id's** to server through the ajax call. how can I do it

Comment: @thomsan: You can get the value of the `<select>` with `$("[id*=ddlPlot]").val()`, which should be an array of strings.  To add that to your `$.ajax()` call you'd use the `data` parameter in the AJAX options: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. Solution is:

1. In your ajax response you need to call another javascript function to load jquery select script & css, it is working fine.

   ```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/link,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            encode  : true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
               $('#ResultDiv').html(data);
                load_script();
            }
        });

    //use load_script function to load script from another view into your current view    
    function load_script(){

     jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/link,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            encode  : true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
               $('#ScriptDiv').html(data);
            }
            });
      }
   ```